# Where are the iCloud Drive icons located?

Tags: macos, icloud

For example, I need to know where the Automator folder icon is. I want to use it for a thing.

Most system folder icons and stuff are in `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/*` But these folder icons are not. Where are they located?

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for either of the following files:

```
/System/Library/PreferencePanes/iCloudPref.prefPane/Contents/Resources/iCloud.icns
```

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder/Contents/Resources/iCloudNoDocs@2x.png
```

Without clarification I can only guess what you want but I think I figured out that you want the folder icons shown within iCloud Drive. It seems like those icons are just a generic folder icon with the relevant app icon superimposed on top of it.